# How to define new classification of files in an eclipse project?

Tags: eclipse, ibm-data-studio

Currently, I am using IBM Data studio for DB2 development. Data Studio is Eclipsed based IDE. We use the data development project template for SP, UDF development. So physically, even though its a flat single folder having all different type of files, when showing in Data Studio, it groups the files as Stored Procedure, Functions, SQL etc. So it must be using some configuration to classify the files and show that under different category. I want to add couple of my own categories and show the files under these new categories. How do I achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is possible (short of writing your own extension to Eclipse). You could raise a RFE (Request for Enhancement) to IBM here https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/

Other options include using the Eclipse native "Project Explorer" or "Navigator" views. The latter allows (for example) to sort by file type. These views all don't hide any folders you create within project, and so you could put your other files types in sub-folders.